# Write math and make a box with alltt environment

Tags: math-mode, verbatim

I tried looking up for this, but I have not found a way to do both at the same time.

I would like to write math symbols in a verbatim like environment, for which I use `alltt`. But I would also like to have my code in a box, for which I used to use `\usepackage{fancyvrb}` and `Verbatim` environment.

Is there a way to combine both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, as explained on page 16 of the `fancyvrb` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},
codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`^=7\catcode`_=8},frame=single]
some code test
$\sum a_i$
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd suggest you to switch to [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) and use its `mathescape=true` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  mathescape=true,
  frame=single
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
some code test
$\sum a_i$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want fancier boxes, then you could use [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its interaction with `listings`.

Comment: Will certainly look up for the listings you have updated, but for my purpose, Verbatim works just fine thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following example derived from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) of `fancyvrb`, section "4.1.6 Catcode characters".

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[
  frame=single,
  commandchars=\\\{\},
  codes={%
    \catcode`$=3\relax
    \catcode`^=7\relax
    \catcode`_=8\relax
  },
]
x\string_0=1/sqrt(z\string^2) ! $x_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2}}$
\end{Verbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}[
  frame=single,
  commandchars=\\\{\},
  codes={%
    \catcode`$=3\relax
  },
]
x_0=1/sqrt(z^2) ! $x\sb{0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z\sp{2}}}$
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

When `_` and `^` have the normal category codes, then they needed to be prefixed by `\string`, if they should be set in verbatim mode.

Alternatively, `_` and `^` are kept unchanged and `\sb` and `\sp` are used in math mode instead.